# Remove margins to get full height using Grid component in material UI

Tags: css, responsive-design, material-ui, grid, responsive

As it can be seen in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-ws29s), I can set the grid container to full height using `100vh` as the `height` value, however the user agent seems to add a margin of `8px` to the body and I haven't found a way to remove it that works.

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ height: "100vh" }}>
    <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} />
    <Grid item xs={8} sx={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} />
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to add `<CssBaseLine />` to reset default margins and paddings.

```
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <CssBaseline/> 
    <Demo />
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Material-UI's Grid uses negative margins for adjusting the spacing. That's why  Grid's parent should have padding that will "fix" that negative margin.

```
<Box paddingTop={2} sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ height: "100vh" }}>
    <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} />
    <Grid item xs={8} sx={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} />
  </Grid>
</Box>
```